# How to get the zoomed area height and width with in the scrollviewer?

Tags: wpf, uwp, scrollview

I want to get the zoomed area height and width in the Scrollviewer.This is my code.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="zoomViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" 
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                  ManipulationMode="All" 
                                  MinZoomFactor="1" 
                                  Margin="0,0,10,0">
                        <Image x:Name="image" Source="Sample.jpg" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

I want to know the image height and width of the image after zooming. Please suggest me.

Comment: Just multiply the `Image` `Height` and `Width` by `ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ScrollViewer Properties]

If you want to get the size of "viewport area" that based on the scale of original image, following is the one.

```
zoomedAreaWidth = ViewPortWidth / ZoomFactor
zoomedAreaHeight = ViewPortHeight / ZoomFactor
```

The image is picked from my blog :)

[ScrollViewer - Zoom into the center of the viewport (in Japanese)](http://ddlgjp.blogspot.jp/2015/01/scrollviewer-zoomin.html)